# Syntax issue on creating MySQL scalar-value function

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to create a function in MySQL that returns the sum of each row's difference between two of its decimal values. This statement works correctly:

`SELECT SUM(ending_mileage - beginning_mileage) AS total_mileage FROM trip;`

When I attempt to put this into a function to be easily accessed in my project, I get syntax errors on the parenthesis after `trip` saying "Statement is incomplete, expecting ';'" and on the `END` saying "END is not valid at this position". Is there some kind of syntax that I am not stating correctly?

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnMileageTotal()
RETURNS DECIMAL
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT SUM(ending_mileage - beginning_mileage) FROM trip);
END;
```

Comment: The code is correct and must work while executed correctly. *saying "Statement is incomplete, expecting ';'"* Looks like you try to execute this statement as common SELECT in Query window which is not correct. Read help for your client. PS. Remove BEGIN-END, they're excess. Simply ```CREATE FUNCTION fnMileageTotal()
RETURNS DECIMAL
RETURN (SELECT SUM(ending_mileage - beginning_mileage) FROM trip);```

Comment: @Akina that works to remove syntax errors. Now, on trying to run the function, it gives me ```Error Code: 1418. This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)```

Comment: Add according definition (`DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA`).

Comment: @Akina perfect! ```SELECT fnMileageTotal()``` now works as intended. Thank you.